# Error 10038 on winsock connect method

Tags: c++, winsock, wsastartup

I'm trying to setup a simple connection with a server app running on the same computer as the client.

My code looks like this:

```
void Base::Connect(string ip, string port)
{
    int status;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  // will point to the results

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); // make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // don't care IPv4 or IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP stream sockets

    // get ready to connect
    status = getaddrinfo(ip.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &servinfo);

    // Socket Setup
    if (ConnectSocket = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("[NETWORKING] An error occured when setting up socket\n");
    }

    // Connect
    if (connect(ConnectSocket, servinfo->ai_addr, (int)servinfo->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("Connect error: ", error);
    }
}
```

Beforehand, I call `WSAStartup()` and it doesn't throw any errors. If the server is on or off the error doesn't change.

the IP I use is 127.0.0.1 and I'm connection through port 80. I've tried something else (1337) which gave me the same error.

Is there something obviously wrong? Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: WSAENOTSOCK. You have a parenthesis error in your socket creation

Comment: where do you see a parentheses error? I can't find anything wrong with the actual socket() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (ConnectSocket = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

You´re comparing socket(...) to `INVALID_SOCKET`
and then you´re assigning the result true/false to ConnectSocket.
Use

```
if ((ConnectSocket = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

See lists of C++ operator precedence

Comment: That solved it (Waiting 7 minutes to flag it as right answer) but now it throws 10061 (Actively refused by...). I have the server running by the way.

Comment: WSAECONNREFUSED: Usually one of following: a) There is no server program at the specified port. b) Firewall settings.

Comment: I shut down my firewall but it still return the 10061 error and the ports are the same (80). I'll look into it some more and create a new question later. Thanks for the help

Comment: `WSAECONNREFUSED` can also mean the server has too many pending clients in its backlog and cannot accept a new connection at that moment.